# command || run code and exit

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I run a command, then an OR so the code block will be executed if the command fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
test || (
 echo "Test failed, exit!"
 exit 1
)
echo "Test succeeded!"
```

This works but the script just continues and doesn't exit, `Test succeeded` is still printed.

I tried using `exec`:

```
test || exec <<EOS
  echo "Test failed, exit!"
EOS
```

But that doesn't run the heredoc at all nor stop the rest of the script...

I am very new to shell scripts.

Comment: It is exiting from the sub-shell you open with `( )`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but you can see I failed to get exec working to replace the current script (and then it would exit fine from that, right?). How can I run the code block without a sub shell?

Comment: Use bash conditionals, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `(..)` starts a subshell. Anything process related you do inside it will only affect that subshell.

Instead, use `{..}` grouping:

```
#!/bin/sh
test || {
 echo "Test failed, exit!"
 exit 1
}
echo "Test succeeded!"
```

The `(..)` behavior is very useful when you actually *do* want to contain effects, such as

```
for dir in */
do 
  ( cd "$dir" && make )  # This 'cd' will be contained inside the ()
done
```

which prevents you from having to keep track of whether you were able to cd in, and therefore whether or not you have to `cd ..` to make it back to where you were.

Comment: +1, entirely correct, but I would encourage OP to use a function to smooth this out: `warn() { printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2; } die() { local st="$1"; shift; warn "$@"; exit $st; }`; that is, two utility functions: one to send warning messages to standard error, and the other to warn and then exit. Then you can just do `test || die $? 'Test failed, exit!'`

Answer (score 3):

@thatOtherGuy has given you the correct answer.

I would encourage you, as a matter of style, if the  `{ grouped block; }` is longer than one line, use `if`:

```
if test; then
    echo "test succeeded"
else
    echo "test failed, exit" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

versus, IMO, the less readable.

```
test || {
    echo "test failed, exit" >&2
    exit 1
}
echo "test succeeded"
```